# Cannot Create Shortcut to Primary Output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010. The primary output of another project is in the application folder. I am having trouble creating a shortcut to this output. I have done some research, and everything I found said to simply right click on the primary output and choose to create a shortcut. However, when I right click on the primary output I am only given the options "Dependencies", "ExcludeFilter", and "Outputs". How can I create a shortcut to a file in this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im having trouble with this also

Try to rebuild your project one time before you add the shortcuts

the "project output"'s icon will change, and you wont be able to add shortcuts anymore.

if you add the shortcut before building, i get an error that the target is invalid on build (and the project output's icon changes also.)

Comment: I have figured out how to avoid this bug:

It will happen everytime you rebuild your setup project using the "batch build" command, so just make sure you always untick it.

When you do, your "project's output target" "key output" is wiped out and the shortcut no longer point to a valid target.


I use batch rebuild all heavily and this is anoying; i'll have to always make sure i dont batch rebuild setup projects and i have to build them manually after.

Answer (score 4):

I found this article, http://geekanddo.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/visual-studio-setup-projects-wont-make-a-shortcut-to-the-primary-output/.

Basically the problem I was experiencing boils down to the output path for the project being invalid. In my case my output path contained $(SolutionDir)\bin. The '\' after $(SolutionDir) actually gives a double '\' in the path ('MySolutionDir\\bin' for example). Removing the extra '\' giving $(SolutionDir)bin fixed my problems.

The trickiest part with tracking this down is that VS will build the output to the expected location silently if it is invalid because of a double '\'

Comment: Worked for me as well. Seems like the QT Plugin is adding those extra slashes to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed your project name is MyApplication1

Follow this Steps

1. Right Click on your ApplicationFolder > Add > Project Output
2. On Project output group select MyApplication1

   this will create **[Primary Ouput from MyApplication1(Active) | Active** on Application folder
3. To create shortcut , just right click **[Primary Ouput from MyApplication1(Active) | Active** then select Create Shortcut to Primary Ouput from MyApplication1(Active).
4. To Add an icon just right click the shortcut. On properties toolbox go to icon and select the image you want.

Then Build your Setup Project.

Regards

Comment: I already have my applications primary output in the Application Folder. When I right click on the Primary Output, creating a shortcut is not one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when converting a VS2008 solution to a VS2010 solution.   The VS solution contains just over 70 C++ projects.  I found two conditions which produced this error.   The first was reported in an MSDN forum (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/winformssetup/thread/884b7d69-8aa6-47f6-8261-30770a45eb09).

The second condition is that VS2010 does not appear to properly update a VS2008 project **.vcproj** file when a linker option uses a particular macro (i.e. the project linker option **[project property pages][Configuration Properties][Linker][General][Output File]**).   Specifically, the setup ‘shortcut’ problem occurred when this option was defined using the **$(OutDir)** macro.   I will explain in a bit more detail.

I found that the setup ‘shortcut’ problem occurred only for those few projects in which the **Output File** option was defined using the **$OutDir** macro.   In contrast, all other projects defined the **Output File** option using the **$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)** macros  - and for these projects, the setup ‘shortcut’  problem did not occur.   I simply replaced **$OutDir** with the **$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)**, resaved the project, and found this corrected the setup ‘shortcut’ problem.

I believe that replacing **$OutDir** with **$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)** caused the VS2010 IDE to update the project **.vcproj** file and it was this process of updating **.vcproj** that corrected the setup ‘shortcut’ problem.    The reason I say this is because I re-defined the **Output File** option using the **$OutDir** macro and this did NOT cause the setup ‘shortcut’ problem to return.  I did not investigate any further because I had already wasted a good deal of time in finding a solution to the problem.